# Monochromatic solutions to $x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots+ x_{m}=x_{m+1}$

Tags: combinatorics, ramsey-theory

What is the least $n$ such that any $2$-coloring of $[n]$ has a monochromatic solution to the equation
$$x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots+ x_{m}=x_{m+1}.$$

I think the answer is $m^{2}+m-1$. I have a coloring of $[m^{2}+m-2]$ with no monochromatic solution. So $n\geq m^{2}+m-1$. I'm looking for the other inequality. But I have no idea how to approach the problem. Any hints would be very nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Below, intervals denote *integer* intervals, that is, $[a,b]=\{n\in\mathbb N\mid a\le n\le b\}$, and the colors are red and blue.)

To see the lower bound, we can consider the coloring where $[1,m-1]\cup[m^2,m^2+m-2]$ is colored red, and $[m,m^2-1]$ is colored blue. This coloring gives us no monochromatic solutions to $$x_1+\dots+x_m=x_{m+1}. $$

To see that any $2$-coloring of $[m^2+m-1]$ gives us a monochromatic solution, proceed by contradiction, and consider a putative counterexample.

- We may assume $\color{red}{1}$ is red, so $\color{blue}{m}=\color{red}{1}\cdot m$ is blue and $\color{red}{m^2}=\color{blue}m\cdot m$ is red.
- Since $\color{red}{1},\color{red}{m^2}$ are red, then $\color{red}{1}\cdot(m-1)+\color{red}{m^2}=\color{blue}{m^2+m-1}$ is blue.
- Since $\color{blue}{m},\color{blue}{m^2+m-1}=\color{blue}{m}\cdot(m-1)+(\color{red}{2m-1})$ are blue, then $\color{red}{2m-1}$ is red, and since $\color{red}{2m-1}=\color{red}{1}+\color{blue}{2}\cdot(m-1)$, then $\color{blue}{2}$ is blue, which gives us that $\color{blue}{2}\cdot(m-1)+\color{blue}{m}=\color{red}{3m-2}$ is red.
- Since $\color{red}{1},\color{red}{3m-2}$ are red, then $\color{red}{1}\cdot(m-1)+\color{red}{3m-2}=\color{blue}{4m-3}$ is blue. But since $\color{blue}{4m-3}=\color{red}{3}\cdot(m-1)+\color{blue}{m}$, then $\color{red}{3}$ is red, and therefore $\color{blue}{m+2}=\color{red}{1}\cdot(m-1)+\color{red}{3}$ is blue.
- We now have a contradiction, since $\color{red}{3}\cdot m=\color{blue}{2}\cdot(m-1)+\color{blue}{m+2}$, and no matter whether $3m$ is red or blue, we obtain a monochromatic solution to our equation, against the assumption.

By the way, in [**Ramsey theory on the integers**](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2020361), by Bruce Landman and Aaron Robertson, you can find this result and generalizations, discussed in section $8.2$. The argument for the upper bound I just showed is an adaptation of a result they prove there (see Theorem $8.21$).

Comment: I totally forgot about this. I came up with a similar argument. Thanks for the article.